# How to map an array values to another array values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am facing difficulties in mapping the values of two arrays to each other. I am having a string array list which is storing the users selected values:

```
private List<String> selectedCertificates = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The above array will store as an example ["SS", "CC", "SC"] and at the same time the user can select a language for certain types but not all of them. For example the type "SS" and the type "CC" should be by default "English" where "SC" can be either English or French or any other language.

```
        String[] DocType = new String[4];
        String[] DocLanguage = new String[4];

        DocType[0] = "CE";
        DocLanguage[0] = "EN";
        DocType[1] = "SC";
        DoctLanguage[1] = "EN";
        DocType[2] = "SS";
        DocLanguage[2] = ssLanguage;
        DocType[3] = "RR";
        DocLanguage[3] = "FR";
```

So now my issue is that I want to have a string array for the selected languages only that it will include ["EN","EN",valueofssLanguage] for the same sequence of the selected certificates ["SS", "CC", "SC"], so how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Hashmap, Hashtable can map from string to string.

Comment: `Map` should fit your needs

Comment: So what should I do I need some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HasMap<>();
map.put(docType[0], "EN");
...
```

You can use [`Map#values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) to get a collection view of the values, that is a collections of languages.

Comment: Should I replace the my code with the above suggested? And how do I get the selectedLanguages in a separate string array?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but will the map will get the values of the languages once the certificates are selected?

Comment: @Learner30 You can retrieve the language corresponding to a specific certificate using `Map.get(certificate)`. See the Javadoc for info about map operations.

Comment: Yes it seems `Map` is the best choice here.

Comment: manouti, correct me if I am wrong. First I will do the mapping as how you specified above in your answer. Then, I would use map.get(selectedCertificates) to get the selected mappings, am I correct? Should I keep it in a for loop? Also, should I delete  DocType[0] = "CE"; from my code?